# safe to shrink volume on linux - does data get deleted

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

My SSD has 250GB of space, and I allocated 75GB for files and 150GB for installation directory. I kind of flipped it. I've got some files on 150GB. I would like to shrink 50GB from installation folder and add that up to the 75GB of space. Will I lose files in the installation partition when I do that? If there is a way to do it safely without losing any files, please mention how.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run a special tool to do this, just resizing the partition without a tool that is aware of the filesystem inside the partition will probably cause massive data loss.

Comment: do you know of any such tools? @JoeyNovak?

Comment: @BumbleBee Gparted in a live session. You can't manage partitions that are in use.